# Follow links in cURL responses using a loop

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl, jq

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" 'http://example.com'
```

the response I get is

```
{"next":"/gibberish"}
```

So I perform another request:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" 'http://example.com/gibberish'
```

the response I get is

```
{"next":"/anotherGibberish"}
```

I want to be able to do the curl request, get the `next` information and loop in to the next request.

Do you guys have any idea how to perform this in bash?

**EDIT:** Any help using jq would also be great.
The last response is a JSON response with an authentication failure - that's where I should stop the loop.

```
{"unauthorized":"Authenticate with username and password"}
```

Comment: @oguzismail when there's no ```{"next":"/anotherGibberish"}```response anymore

Comment: Yes. The final response is an authentication failure ```{"unauthorized":"Authenticate with username and password"}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `next` key is either nonexistent in the response or its value is a string forming a valid URL when prepended to `http://example.com`:

```
#!/bin/bash -
next=/
while resp=$(curl -sS "http://example.com$next"); do
  if ! next=$(jq -er '.next' <<< "$resp"); then
    # `resp' is the final response here
    # , do whatever you want with it
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: this worked greatly with just one modification. In the curl request I added the header ```-H "Accept: application/json"``` - Thanks a lot!